# How to correctly initialize a Comparator?

Tags: java, string, initialization, comparator

I need to write a static method in a class MinTester that computes the "smallest" string 
from an ArrayList collection using a comparator object:

```
public static String min(ArrayList<String> list, Comparator<String> comp)
```

I cannot use the Collections class to compute the minimum.

Here is what I have so far.

```
public class MinTester 
{
    public static String min(ArrayList<String> list, Comparator<String> comp)
    {
        String shortest = list.get(0);

        for(String str : list) {
            if ( comp.compare(str, shortest) < 0) {
                shortest = str;
            }
        }
        return shortest;
    }
}
```

I am not getting any errors here from the method, So I try to test it in Main with this. 
I get this error when trying to pass comp: Variable comp may not have been initialized

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here

    MinTester s = new MinTester();
    Comparator<String> comp;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("a");
    list.add("ab");
    list.add("abc");
    list.add("abcd");

    String a = s.min(list,comp);//Error: Variable comp may not have been initialized

    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Heres where I run into my problem.

I try

```
Comparator<String> comp = new Comparator<>();//Error:Comparator is abstract, cannot be instantiated
Comparator<String> comp = new MinTester();//Error: MinTester cannot be converted to Comparator<String>
```

Can anyone tell me the proper way to handle this Comparator?  Im not sure if Im just trying to initialize it incorrectly, or if I'm missing something in my MinTester class.

Comment: You can read my article concerning this (should be updated soon) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703185/Comparator-and-Comparable-objects

Comment: You haven't defined what you mean by "smallest".  You imply in your code that you mean "shortest", but I suspect the definition is a little more complex, as in "shortest but in the event of a tie, sort according to character collation sequence (i.e. alphabetically for letters)".  Once you know that, implement `Comparator<String>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write a class that implements `Comparator<String>` for this. A quick approach using [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
String a = s.min(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
});
```

Since you need to compare based on String length, just change the comparison logic in the `compare` method:

```
String a = s.min(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return (s1.length() > s2.length()) ? 1 : (s1.length() < s2.length()) ? -1 : 0;
    }
});
```

If you happen to use Java 7, then use `Integer#compare`:

```
String a = s.min(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
    }
});
```

If you use Java 8, you can use a lambda expression:

```
String a = s.min(list, (s1, s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length()));
```

Comment: `Comparator` is an interface. It should be 'implemented' not extended.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I tried this, and my output for a seems to be based by alphabetical order, not comparing lengths.  If I have 'b' and 'abc', a will = abc because a comes before b.  I would try and edit it, but I am not sure how this anonymous method goes hand in hand with the method from my MinTester class

Comment: Then replace the body of the compare method by code which compares the length of the strings. Should not be longer that 1 line.

Comment: @user3345200 You just have to replace the exact same line where you have `String a = s.min(list, comp);` by this one. If you need to compare by String length, then change the implementation.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: `return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());`

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, I always miss the Java 7 way to do it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  Thank you, this fixed my problem.  If I wanted to handle the condition where i have 2 string the same length that are the shortest, ex. 'a' and 'b', would I have to handle that in the anon  class as well?

Comment: @user3345200 you could do it in the class that implements the `Comparator`. For example, instead of returning `0`, add another condition to compare them alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

`Comparator` is an interface; different classes can implement it in different ways to perform different kinds of comparisons.  The reason why your method takes a `Comparator` is so that the caller can choose how the strings should be compared.  Pass in a `Comparator` that does lexical (aka alphabetical) comparison, and you'll get the first string in lexical order.  Pass in a `Comparator` that looks at string length, and you'll get the shortest string.

Since the `String` class already implements the `Comparable` interface — a sort of sibling to `Comparator` that lets a class define its own comparison method — here's a handy generic class that lets you use any `Comparable` through the `Comparator` interface:

```
public final class ComparableComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T> {
    @Override
    public int compare(final T a, final T b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

Pass one of those into your method and it'll compare the strings using the `String` class's own `compareTo` method.

**Edit:**  In Java 8 or later, the [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) method gives you the same thing, so you don't need to write the class above.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to use `Comparator`, at least not unless you want to modify the natural ordering of the string comparisons. Use the `compareTo()` method for the `String` class instead.

```
if (str.compareTo(shortest) < 0) {
     shortest = str;
}
```

If at all you wish to modify the natural ordering, you can create a class which implements the `Comparator` interface and then pass an instance of this class to the `compare()` method. You can also define your own logic for the comparisons.

```
public class StringDescComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        // return str1.compareTo(str2);      // For natural ordering
        return -1 * str1.compareTo(str2);    // For reversed ordering
    }
}
```

Then you can use an instance of the above class to compare in the descending order such that: `"b" < "a"`

```
Comparator comp = new StringDescComparator();
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, using a `Comparator` is a requirement.  (This sounds like a school assignment.)

Comment: Ohh! Then you can use the `Comparator` class in my answer with the return statement as `return str1.compareTo(str2);` to preserve the natural ordering